# Discrete maths: Solving for n

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone point me in the right direction for solving this: Find the smallest positive integer n such that $138, 411n = x^3$ for some integer $x$

So what I first did was break $138,411$ down into its unique prime factorisation, which gave me: $138,411 = 3^2 * 7^1 * 13^3$

From there I thought I should make all the powers on the primes 3 because of the $x^3$, which would make my $ n =3 * 7 * 7 = 147$

But then $138,411(147) = 20,346,417$ and $147^3 = 3,176,523$

So I'm unsure about how to progress from here.

Regards.

Comment: $20346417=(3\cdot 7 \cdot 13)^3=273^3\,$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Oh I think I was misunderstanding the question, but I got it now. Cheers for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cube has each prime factor appearing a multiple of $3$ times, so your $n$ has to increase the multiplicity of each factor to a multiple of $3$.  You start with $3^2$, so need one factor of $3$ and so on.

Comment: Yep! I misunderstood and thought n and x had to be the same value, but got it now. Thanks